# Internationalization at HTML5

Tags: validation, html, email-validation

How can I change the messages of HTML5 (or doses it change according to browser's language automatically?)

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>    
<html>    
<body>        

<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">

E-mail: <input type="email" name="user_email" /><br />

<input type="submit" />

</form>


</body>    
</html>
```

When I run this code (from [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_form_email)) at Opera and write a non valid e-mail address it says

```
Please enter a valid email address
```

How can I change it to another language instead of English or change the warning to what I want?

Comment: Unless you're providing that message yourself and you're not using any library that provides it, I think it's safe to assume that the browser will provide the message in the language it's installed in.

Comment: The Internationalization has to do with the asp pages. You need to wrap around the validation class and make your own messages.

Comment: To make this more general, I'd also be really interested if the display of those browser-generated messages can be customized. The Chrome way of displaying validation errors is pretty ugly. Maybe you could extend this question to generally cover "How to customize HTML5 validation"?

Comment: @Vince2doom The `<input type="email">` makes those browsers that support this feature validate the form before it's sent to the server.

Comment: @Vince2doom I understand that validation should be at server side but I want to use the power of HTML5 and show that message i.e. at Turkish.

Comment: @Juhana I thought with the reference to the ASP page in the action attribute, it was an ASP issue. But now it's clear that it is the email validator of html5 I am sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Well there are different options.

1. You can disable the form validation of the form (or the field) with formnovalidate and provide a custom error message with javascript (and serverside ofcourse).
2. You can use javascript and use the `.setCustomValidity()` method to provide a (custom) error message but it is intended to add extra rules to the field.
3. You can use `x-moz-errormessage` to set a custom errormessage. But using this you need to know that this is not a standard.

Answer (score 2):

There are no built-in internationalisation solutions currently in HTML(5) and all proposals seem [dead](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/I18n).  However you may find the [Passive Localisation](http://eligrey.com/blog/post/passive-localization-in-javascript) JavaScript library of some use. Online demonstration can be found [here](http://code.eligrey.com/l10n.js/demo.html).